# SQL - IN (Select ... ) Performance issue

Tags: sql, performance, select

I know in (select...) stuff should be avoided but in my situation I couldn't find another way to do it.

Unfortunately, as the database is huge, I would like to find a better way. So could you please share your experience to optimise the query below ?

Here is an idea of the db

```
ID   OrderRef   Product    OrderDate   ShipmentDate    Client

1    111        T-Shirt    1/1/2018    4/1/2018        Georges
2    111        Pull-Over  1/1/2018    6/1/2018        (Unknown)
3    222        Shoes      9/1/2018    15/1/2018       Austin
4    222        T-Shirt    9/1/2018    18/1/2018       (Unknown)
```

What I need to retrieve is :

- the data linked to Georges' order (here row 1 and 2). But as you see the Client in the second row is 'unknown'.
- the latest shipment date (-> max(t2.ShipmentDate)) linked to a particular order grouped by Reference

Here is my code

```
SELECT t1.OrderRef, t1.Product, t1.OrderDate, t1.Client, t4.max_date
FROM table1 as t1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT t2.OrderRef, max(t2.ShipmentDate) as max_date
            FROM table1 as t2
            WHERE t2.OrderRef in(
                            SELECT t3.OrderRef 
                            FROM table1 as t3
                            WHERE t3.Client='Georges')
            GROUP BY t2.OrderRef) as t4 on t2.OrderRef=t1.OrderRef
```

The right join is there to retrieve only the OrderReference linked to Georges, and the subquery to calculate the the Latest ShipmentDate

- Is there a more efficient way to reach this result ?
- As t1,t2,t3 are linked to the same table. I think this is more readable this way, but for a matter of performance should I use only one single name for them ?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Largo

Comment: You often get much better performance by either using a join or using EXISTS instead of using IN. You could easily re-write your inner query to make use of that. Not sure if that completely fixes your issue though, that could only be determined if you included an execution plan (that would highlight if there were missing indexes or non-performant indexes that could be broadend).

Comment: I'll second that - selecting from inside a where in seems like the wrong approach

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be retrieving a few rows only on each call. This should be pretty fast even if you have billions of rows. I would do something like:

```
with
a as (
  select max(orderref) as orderref
  from t
  where client = 'Georges'
),
b as (
  select t.* 
  from t
  join a on a.orderref = t.orderref
),
c as (
  select max(shipmentdate) as maxshipmentdate from b
)
select b.*, c.maxshipmentdate
from b
cross join c
```

The query above should be pretty fast is you have the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on t (client);
create index ix2 on t (orderref);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use (correlated) subqueries.

```
SELECT t11.orderref,
       t11.product,
       t11.orderdate,
       t11.client,
       (SELECT max(t13.shipmentdate)
               FROM table1 t13
               WHERE t13.orderref = t11.orderref) max_date
       FROM table1 t11
       WHERE t11.orderref = (SELECT t12.orderref
                                    FROM table1 t12
                                    WHERE t12.client = 'Georges');
```

To support the subquery getting the `orderref` an index like

```
CREATE INDEX table1_c_or
             ON table1 (client ASC,
                        orderref ASC);
```

should help. That subquery is "pointy" anyway.

For getting the maximum `shipmentdate`

```
CREATE INDEX table1_or_sd
             ON table1 (orderref ASC,
                        shipmentdate DESC);
```

should help. The optimizer should notice that the maximum needs to be retrieved only once as the `orderref` is always the same. That index can also be used to support the outer query as `orderref` is its first key.

Optionally creating an additional index like

```
CREATE INDEX table1_or_p_od_c
             ON table1 (orderref ASC,
                        product ASC,
                        orderdate ASC,
                        client ASC);
```

might even better support the outer query. But that's not a necessity I guess.